# Private DM command (discord.js)

Tags: discord.js

So i need help making a command were i can say "?DM @user {message content}" and it will find that user in the server and the bot will send them a private message with the senders user name and then there custom message

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Very rarely do people just simply write code for you. We'd like to see you put some effort into your code and display it in the question. Check out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you want to see how.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<client>.users.cache.get("User ID here").send("Message to Send")
```

You can get the `ID` of the mentioned user like this:

```
const mentionedUserID = message.mentions.members.first();
```

I recommend using the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) while you're coding ur bot. It may look a bit overwhelming but it is **very** helpful

Answer (score 0):

This Should Work:

```js
const mention = message.mentions.users.first(); //Mention First.
if (!mention) { //If No Mention.
    return message.channel.send("You didn't mention a user.");
} else {
    if (!args.slice(1).join(" ")) { //If No Message.
        return message.channel.send("Provide a message to say.");
    }
}
client.users.cache.get(mention.id).send(args.slice(1).join(" ")); 
//Sends The Message To The User That You Mentioned
```